# How can I do simple order based validation on a collection of objects with LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

Given a single collection of objects I want to determine if certain objects only appear after another object.

For example say I had a list of strings such as

A B B b b a a C c

I'd want to check if for every lower case letter there is at least as many upper case letters that appears before it in the sequence. Thus the above sequence would be invalid since there are two lower case 'a' and only one 'A'). But the following would be valid:

A a B b

A B a b

A B b a

B A a b

...

Is there way to do that using LINQ?

Comment: Well, you could shoehorn LINQ into the usual "keep an array of 26 ints, add one to `arr[c - 'A']` for every uppercase letter, check if zero and subtract one from `arr[c - 'a']` for every lowercase letter" solution...

Comment: @Anon, that would be the easiest way to solve the above example as presented, but I’m looking for a LINQ solution because I’m trying to understand if it is possible to use LINQ in such a way that’s hard for me to explain but that the solution to the above example would clarify it for me (or even knowing it’s not possible).So I’m asking the question not to find a solution to the problem per say, but just to figure a few other things out:).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean an `IEnumerable<char>` rather than an `IEnumerable<string>`?

Using the **`Rollup`** extension-method described [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2010/02/15/rollup-extension-method-create-running-totals-using-linq-to-objects.aspx) ("a cross between the `Select` and `Aggregate` extension methods"), you could do:

```
IEnumerable<char> chars = ...

bool isValid = chars.Where(char.IsLetter)
                    .GroupBy(char.ToUpperInvariant)
                    .SelectMany(g => g.Rollup(0, 
                                (c, sum) => sum + (char.IsUpper(c) ? 1 : -1)))
                    .All(runningTotal => runningTotal >= 0);
```

For completeness, the code for that method is given as:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> Rollup<TSource, TResult>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    TResult seed,
    Func<TSource, TResult, TResult> projection)
{
    TResult nextSeed = seed;
    foreach (TSource src in source)
    {
        TResult projectedValue = projection(src, nextSeed);
        nextSeed = projectedValue;
        yield return projectedValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!!! That's a really neat way to use LINQ. I'll admit it took me a few minutes to wrap my head around it :), but now that I got it I can think of a whole bunch of new ways I could be using LINQ. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It can be very easy:

```
bool isValid = !source.Where(char.IsLetter)
                     .Where((ch, index) =>
                         {
                            var temp = source.Take(index+1);
                            return temp.Count(c => c == char.ToUpper(c)) 
                                   < temp.Count(c => c == char.ToLower(c));
                         })
                     .Any();
```

Comment: +1. I think you need 2 fixes: 1. `Take(index + 1)` and 2. A `!` at the beginning or to rename the variable to `isInvalid`.

Comment: @Ani: Correct. Thanks for your advice! I have modified my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one too

```
List<string> lstString = new List<string>();
        lstString.Add("A");
        lstString.Add("a");
        lstString.Add("A");
        lstString.Add("a");
        lstString.Add("B");
        lstString.Add("b");
        lstString.Add("B");
        lstString.Add("b");
        lstString.Add("C");
        lstString.Add("c");
        lstString.Add("C");
        lstString.Add("c");

        List<string> uniqueList = (from lst in lstString select lst).Distinct().ToList();
```